# I want to display student Details using constructor method

Tags: php, constructor

I want to display student Details using the constructor method. had try below code, but not sure about that the code method is correct or not.

```
<?php
class Student
{
    function __construct($name, $rollNum, $fatherName, $marks, $totalMarks, $percentage)
    {
        $this -> name = $name;
        $this -> rollNum = $rollNum;
        $this -> fatherName = $fatherName;
        $this -> marks = $marks;
        $this -> totalMarks = $totalMarks;
        $this -> percentage = $percentage;
    }
   
    public function getStudentDetails(){
        echo $this -> name ." " . $this -> rollNum ." " . $this -> fatherName;
    }

    public function getStudentMarks(){
        echo $this -> marks . " " . $this -> totalMarks . " " . $this -> percentage;
    }
}

$student = new Student('John', 007, "McCarty David", 70, 100, 70);
echo $student -> getStudentDetails();
echo '<br>';
echo $student -> getStudentmarks();

?>
```

Comment: Which is the problem if all work?

Comment: Is constructor method program is OK or Not...?

Answer (score 1):

'Constructor' must only construct your object and yours is fine.

'get' methods must return some data or elaboration on your object's members. Using in another way (to display information as in your case) brings you to another error: doing echo of an echo.

You shuld rename your methods as 'displayStudentsMarks' or 'displayStudentDetails' (same body) so you will call them as:

```
$student->displayStudentMarks();
echo '<br>';
$student->displayStudentDetails();
```

and is less likely you will write 'echo displayStudentMarks();' since you'll notice a repetition. Otherwise you have to change the body of theese to methods to get various members values (one at a time, not two groups). Maybe in your case is easier the first change.

In any case if you want for some reason a constructor that does construction and display, you simply add both 'echo' instructions in your constructor:

```
class Student
{
    function __construct($name, $rollNum, $fatherName, $marks, $totalMarks, $percentage)
    {
        $this -> name = $name;
        $this -> rollNum = $rollNum;
        $this -> fatherName = $fatherName;
        $this -> marks = $marks;
        $this -> totalMarks = $totalMarks;
        $this -> percentage = $percentage;
        echo $this -> name ." " . $this -> rollNum ." " . $this -> fatherName;
echo '<br>';
        echo $this -> marks . " " . $this -> totalMarks . " " . $this -> percentage;
    }
```

but you can also call other members in constructor:

```
class Student
{
    function __construct($name, $rollNum, $fatherName, $marks, $totalMarks, $percentage)
    {
        $this -> name = $name;
        $this -> rollNum = $rollNum;
        $this -> fatherName = $fatherName;
        $this -> marks = $marks;
        $this -> totalMarks = $totalMarks;
        $this -> percentage = $percentage;
        $this->displayStudentDetails();
        echo '<br>';
        $this->displayStudentMarks();
    }

    public function displayStudentDetails(){
        echo $this -> name ." " . $this -> rollNum ." " . $this -> fatherName;
    }

    public function displayStudentMarks(){
        echo $this -> marks . " " . $this -> totalMarks . " " . $this -> percentage;
    }
}
```

In both cases you will need only an instruction to construct and display your object:

```
$student = new Student('John', 007, "McCarty David", 70, 100, 70);
```

but as I previous mentioned, is a bad practice (single responsibility).